# Prove by induction $n! > n^2$

Tags: induction, factorial

I am trying to prove the inequality in the title for $n\geq 4$; however, I am stuck on the induction step! Any help would be appreciated.

For $n\ge 4$, prove that $n! > n^2$.

Base Case:
$n=4$, LHS $4! = 24$, RHS = $4^2 = 16$

$24>16$ : True

Induction Hypothesis: Assume True for $n=k$.

$k! > k^2$

Induction Step: Should be True for $n=k+1$

$(k+1)! > (k+1)^2$

$(k+1) . (k)!  > (k^2 + 2k + 1)$

However, here is where I get stuck.

Comment: $k! > k^2 \Rightarrow (k+1)k! > (k+1)k^2$. Now, can you show that for $k \geq 4$ we have

$$(k+1)k^2 > (k+1)^2$$

That is

$$k^2 > k + 1$$

Comment: @GeorgeS wrong question...

Comment: Yes, I just realised. Sorry that was an accident.

Comment: @ClementC. - Can I ask how you got to $(k+1)k^2$?

Comment: You're ultimately trying to show that $(k+1)! > (k+1)^2$, so think of working *towards* this, not *from* it. It should be your last line.

Comment: @Théophile Unless, like in this example, the steps are reversible. Still, caution is advised if you are working "from" the result.

Comment: Not proposing to close, just linking to the [node](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1140396) of this network of duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

$$(k+1)!> (k+1)^2$$
can be rewritten as

$$(k+1)\cdot (k!) > (k+1)\cdot(k+1)$$

Answer (score 1):

For the induction step, here is the key part:
\begin{align}
(k+1)! &= (k+1)\cdot k!\tag{by definition}\\[0.5em]
&> (k+1)\cdot k^2\tag{by the inductive hypothesis}\\[0.5em]
&= k^3+k^2\tag{expand}\\[0.5em]
&> k^2+2k+1\tag{since $k\geq 4$}\\[0.5em]
&= (k+1)^2.
\end{align}
The *main* problem is realizing that you can deduce that $k^3+k^2>k^2+2k+1$ from the fact that $k\geq 4$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume, for $n = k$, the inequality above holds. 
It will be shown, that for $n = k + 1$, the inequality above also holds.

Since $$k! > k^2,$$
then $$(k + 1)k! > (k + 1)k^2,$$
which can be rewritten as $$(k + 1)! > (k^3 + k^2)$$

Since $k \ge 4$, $k^2 \ge 16$, and it follows that $k^3 \ge 16k$.
Additionally, $14k > 1$, and $k^3 > k^2$

So, $$k^3+k^2 \ge k^3 + 16k = k^3 + 2k + 14k > k^2 + 2k + 1$$
Hence, $$(k + 1)! > (k^3 + k^2) > k^2 + 2k + 1 = (k +1)^2 $$.