# Proof using induction: $n! > n^2$, for $n\geq4$

Tags: proof-writing, induction

Proof using induction: $n! > n^2$, for $n\geq4$

- Basis:
  For n = 4, we have:
  $4! > 4^2$
  $24 > 16$ (TRUE)
- Inductive step:

  By the induction hypothesis:
  $k! > k^2$
  $(k+1)k! > (k+1)k^2$
  $(k+1)! > k^3 + k^2$
  But, $k^3 + k^2 > k^2 + 2k + 1$, for $k\geq4$

So, 
$(k+1)! > k^3 + k^2 > k^2 + 2k + 1$
$(k+1)! > (k+1)^2$ ---> What we want to proof

Does this serve as a proof for my sentence?

Comment: It does. Good work.

Comment: I would make one small adjustment in your proof. In you line:$$k^3 + k^2 > k^2 + 2k + 1\text{ for }n\ge4$$you should change the $n$ to a $k$.

Comment: Not proposing to close, just linking to the [node](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1140396) of this network of duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Vinicius No need to make that so complicated.

Assuming $k! > k^2$.
$$(k+1)!>(k+1)^2$$
$$(k+1)k! > (k+1)(k+1)$$
$$k!>k+1$$

The last statement requires little proof for $k \in \{4, 5, 6, \cdots\}$.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively lesser steps. We want to prove $(k+1)!>(k+1)^2$ ie proving $k!>(k+1)$ which is by observation or gamma function true thats all.

Comment: The Gamma function certainly seems too advanced for this level of problem. More important, the problem statement says to prove "using induction," which your answer does not do. But your idea is certainly good.

Comment: I have just written last induction step and reason for the same nothing more and thanks!