# Mathematical induction with an inequality and factorial notation: $n! > n^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, induction, factorial

I'm having difficulty proving
$n! > n^2$ for $n \ge 4$
I have previously solved a similar problem but it is $n! > 2^n$. Now I don't know how to solve this.
I have only come as far as solving for the base case. Thank you so much for helping a struggling student out.

Comment: See also [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1140396/prove-by-induction-that-n2n) and other questions [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1140396).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem is $$n!>n^2 \space \forall n\ge4$$

We'll try to tackle it using induction:

Base case: $$4!>16$$

Hypothesis: $$n!>n^2$$

Induction: $$(n+1)!>(n+1)^2 \Rightarrow (n+1)(n)!\gt(n+1)^2 \Rightarrow n!\gt\frac{(n+1)^2}{(n+1)} \Rightarrow \bbox[border:1px solid red]{n!\gt n+1}$$

The induction is proved.

Comment: how come it suddenly became (n+1)(n)! ?

Comment: $(n+1)!$ is $(n+1)(n)(n-1)...(2)(1)$ right? Therefore it can also be seen, by "taking away" $(n+1)$ from the factorial, as simply $(n+1)$ times my old factorial $n!$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try to justify
\begin{align}
 n(n^2-2n+1) \ge n^2.
\end{align}
for $n\geq 4$.